# Не работает cron | CentOs 7 | Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, cron

Почему не выполняются консольные команды Cron на CentOs 7?

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

**crontab** file

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=

01 * * * * /var/www/main/www/public_html/yii replication/get-entities >> /vat/log/console-app.log 2>&1
```

> sudo systemctl start crond.service

```
$ sudo systemctl status crond.service
   ● crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Вт 2017-04-25 12:33:18 MSK; 27s ago
   Main PID: 7326 (crond)
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
        └─7326 /usr/sbin/crond -n

апр 25 12:33:18 luna.server systemd[1]: Started Command Scheduler.
апр 25 12:33:18 luna.server systemd[1]: Starting Command Scheduler...
апр 25 12:33:18 luna.server crond[7326]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 70% if used.)
апр 25 12:33:18 luna.server crond[7326]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
апр 25 12:33:18 luna.server crond[7326]: (CRON) INFO (@reboot jobs will be run at computer's startup.)
апр 25 12:33:41 luna.server systemd[1]: Started Command Scheduler.



$ ps -ef | grep cron
227:root      7326     1  0 12:33 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/crond -n
231:puganovs  7408  6174  0 12:38 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -in cron
```

В файл **console-app.log** ничего не падает.
Из консоли команда **yii replication/get-entities** выполняется без проблем. В чем может быть проблема?
Пробовал еще так:

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/main/www/public_html/yii replication/get-entities
```

Comment: у вас опечатка в /va**r**/log/console-app.log, пути с /vat не существует, и система просто не может ничего записать в такой файл

Comment: У меня нечто похожее было с node.js. Там есть процесс, который надо перезапустить по cron после перезагрузки. Казалось бы, простая команда: `/var/www/ghost/forever start index.js`. С консоли выполнялась без проблем, из cron - никак, пока я не создал файл start-ghost.sh, в нем записал по export необходимые PATH и - самое смешное - сделал так: `cd /var/www/ghost` `forever start index.js`. Ну и созданный файл start-ghost.sh воткнул в cron вместо команды. Так работает. Попробуйте покрутиться вокруг этого, вдруг поможет.

Comment: А зачем вы выключили рассылку на мейл, вам не интересны сообщения об ошибках?

Comment: Исправьте пожалуйста `vat`  на `var`, oто такое ощущение что вы не следите за вашим вопросом.Или отреагируйте на какой нибудь коммент.

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал @etki, у Вас опечатка в названии пути "/vat/log/console-app.log 2>&1". Исправьте на "/var/log/console-app.log 2>&1"